# How does instruction after Load, execute?

Tags: pipeline, cpu-architecture, pipelining

There are 5 stages in pipeline.

```
IF -  Instruction fetch
ID -  Instruction Decode, read the register  
EX -  On a memeory reference add up base and offset, 
      and for arithmetic instruction do the math.   
MEM - If load or store access memory
WB -  Place the result in appropriate register.     



 I1 : R0 <- M[loc]      IF | ID | EX | MEM | WB |

 I2 - R0 <- R0 + R0                  | IF  | ID | EX | MEM | WB  | 

 I3 - R2 <- R2 - R0                        | IF | ID | EX  | MEM | WB |
```

Consider that "Operand Forwarding " has been used.
Solution says :-

> Instruction `I1` is a `Load` instruction. So the next instruction ( `I2`) cannot fetch until `I1` finishes its `EXE` stage.

But I think: in `MEM` stage, the processor accesses the memory and picks the desired word. And in `WB` stage it updates Registry of Register.
So until `MEM` stage the processor holds the control of Memory, so `I2`  will start fetching after `MEM` of `I1`.

Which one is correct?

Description of stages has not been given, it is written as per my knowledge.

Comment: I edited your question. If you find my edits unpleasant, you can rollback them by using the "edit" button on the lower left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention:

> *I* denote a generic instruction.
>   *I1*, *I2*, *I3*, ... denote specific instructions.
>   *S* denote a generic stage of the pipeline.
>   *IF*, *ID*, *EX*, *MEM*, *WB* denote a specific stages of the pipeline.
>   *I.S* denote the cycle in which the instruction *I* was in the stage *S*.

The instruction *I2* needs *R0* but that register won't be ready from *I1* until *I1.WB* has finished, assuming a basic pipeline.
With operand forwarding present, *I2* can read the result while *I1* is writing it back into the register file, that is during *I1.WB*.

Since the operand is read in the *ID* stage, *I2.ID* and *I1.WB* must happen at the same time.
That means that *I2.IF* must happen at the same time of *I1.MEM*.

---

Now you are rightfully dubious about the ability of the CPU to perform two reads (one for the instruction fetching and one for the load) in the same clock.
Very simple CPUs actually stalls on such conflict (in your example the *I2.IF* would happen at *I1.WB*).

The simplest approach to avoid a stall is the [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture), where the CPU fetches instructions from a different memory.

The Harvard architecture [has been modified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture#Contrast_with_modified_Harvard_architecture) through the use of caches and pre-fetching of data and instructions.
In this context a stall occurs only if both the load and the instruction fetching need to access the memory (and not the caches).

Modern desktop architectures have L1 data cache that can handle more that one access at a time and the CPU is tightly coupled with them so that two or more loads/stores can be executed at the same time, in parallel with loads from L1 instruction cache.

Finally some of the modern CPUs decode more than one instruction at a time, alleviating the problem of the stall (but not eliminating it).
It is the cache that provide the greatest benefit in avoiding stalls though.